# Как распознать одиночный символ в pytesseract?

Tags: python, pytesseract

Есть такая вот функция:

```
def screenGrab():
    for coord in COORDS:
        box = (coord[0][0], coord[0][1]+20, coord[1][0], coord[1][1]-44)
        base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
        im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\screen'+ '.png', 'PNG')
        image = base_dir + r'\screen.PNG'

        image = cv2.imread(image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



        scale_percent = 400  # percent of original size
        width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        resized_img = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_img, (3, 3), 0)
        blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(blur_img, 3)

        thresh, new_img = cv2.threshold(blur_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        filename_dir = base_dir + "\gray.png"
        cv2.imwrite(filename_dir, new_img)
        image = Image.open('gray.png')


        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='outputbase digits'))
```

И такое изображение:

[image: 2048]

(я беру по 1 квадрату в цикле)

Этот код хорошо распознает цифры 16, 32, 128, 256 и тд., но 2, 4, 8 не хочет распознавать, вообще ничего не выводит. Может, нужно какой-то особый конфиг задать?